# React Redux Image Wont load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

So this could honestly be as simple as just over looking it and staring for so long and being new to react but on my section component I'm loading in my backgroundImg prop wont load the image and I cant figure it out. My pictures are in the public folder and my code is in the src components folder

Also, I can get images to load in the file just not when I'm calling them through prop

Home.js     This is where I am calling my component and trying to load the file in through the prop type

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import Section from './Section'


function Home() {
    return (
        <Container>
            <Section 
                title="Model S"
                description="Order Online for Touchless Delivery"
                backgroundImg='/public/pictures/model-s.jpg'
                leftBtnText="Custom Order"
                rightBtnText="Existing Inventory"
            />
            <Section 
                title="Model E"
                description="Order Online for Touchless Delivery"
                backgroundImg=".\Pictures\model-e.jpg"
                leftBtnText="Custom Order"
                rightBtnText="Existing Inventory"
            />
            <Section />
            <Section />
            
        </Container>
    )
}

export default Home

//Home and styled help you stlye the component without using css

const Container = styled.div`
    height: 100vh;
`
```

Section.js           The component for the Screen

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'


//props are just parameters you can set when calling the component

function Section(props) {
    
    return (
        <Wrap bgImg={props.backgroundImg}>
            <ItemText>
                <h1>{props.title}</h1>
                <p>{props.description}</p>
            </ItemText>
            <Buttons>
                <ButtonGroup>
                    <LeftButton>
                        {props.leftBtnText}
                    </LeftButton>
                    <RightButton>
                        {props.rightBtnText}
                    </RightButton>
                </ButtonGroup>
                <DownArrow src='/Pictures/down-arrow.svg' />
            </Buttons>
        </Wrap>
    )
}

export default Section

const Wrap = styled.div`
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
`

const ItemText = styled.div`
    padding-top: 15vh;
    text-align: center;
`

const ButtonGroup = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    @media (max-width: 786px){
        flex-direction: column;
    }
`

const LeftButton = styled.div`
    background-color: rgba(23, 26, 32, 0.8);
    height: 40px;
    width: 256px;
    color: white;
    display: flex; 
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 100px;
    opacity: 0.85;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 8px;
`

const RightButton = styled(LeftButton)`
    background: white;
    opacity: 0.65;
    color: black;
`

const DownArrow = styled.img`
    margin-top: 20px;
    height: 40px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    animation: animateDown infinite 1.5s;
`

const Buttons = styled.div`

`


Thanks for the help.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but it looks like you didn't use the Wrap `bgImg` prop in the styled component.  There is background-size, background-position, background-repeat, but not background-image using the prop.

Example:
`background-image: ${props => props.bgImg || ''};`

https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#passed-props